# How to apply a css class in a element that hasn't been rendered yet?

Tags: javascript

I need to add a css class to an element that when the page is loaded is still not created. It gets created only when the dropdown is open. This is my code below where I loop through a list and add a class to the elements but, as I said, the class '.dropdown-popup-row' is not found because the drop starts closed.

What I'm doing at the moment is verify if '.dropdown-list' exists in the body (if so, it means that the dropdown is open)

```
const str = "[0,1,2]";
const arr = JSON.parse(str);

var dropdownList = document.querySelector('.dropdown-list');

if (document.body.contains(dropdownList)) {
    var dropdownElements = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-popup-row');

    if(dropdownElements) {

    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var disabledIndex = arr[i];
        dropdownElements[disabledIndex].classList.add("-disabled");
    }
}
}
```

this works fine in the browser console with the dropdown open (therefore .dropdown-list is rendered and available in the DOM). I can't figure out a way to add this class to this element. The error I've been getting is: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined".

Thank you guys!

Comment: have you tried DOMContentLoaded event listner

Comment: What's the mechanism that's adding the dropdown elements and when do they get loaded?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you add that class when that element is being created?
Is it created by an external library ?

Comment: That's right my friend! It's been added by an external script.

Comment: Can u edit this script ? If so just add your class there, if not why don't you check if there is some feedback event from that script

Answer (score 0):

If you have `dropDownElements`, you should be able to safely iterate over them as opposed to iterating over your list of disabled indexes.  Something like:

```
if (document.body.contains(dropdownList)) {
    var dropdownElements = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-popup-row');

    // For each dropdown item
    dropdownElements.forEach(function(element, i) {
        // If the index corresponds to one in the list, disable it
        if (arr.includes(i)) {
            element.classList.add("-disabled");
        }
    });
}
```

In your original code, there's the possibility that an index in the array does not match to an item in your dropdown, which could lead to the error you received. For example if there's a `4` in your array and only four elements in your dropdown, `dropdownElements[4]` will be undefined. In my code above, there's no chance of this because it's iterating over the elements in the dropdown instead.

If the problem is truly that your dropdown elements are only rendered after the dropdown is selected, you might run the above code when `dropdownList` gets focused or clicked.

Comment: Thank you Ed! This way I'm not getting the error no more but the class isn't being applied too. The thing is I only dropdownElements (array of 4 elements) when the dropdown is opened when it's closed I got an empty array.

Comment: Thank you guys! I finally made it. I needed to set an setInterval function watching when the element was created in the DOM an only then add the class!